# Access Element in JSON data that doesn't have a standard name

Tags: php, json, rest

I'm using the Kraken API to get a list of available currency pairings.

Here is the endpoint: https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs

```
$kraken_coins = 
file_get_contents('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs');
$kraken_coins = json_decode($kraken_coins, true);

foreach ($kraken_coins['result'] as $coin) {    
    echo $coin . "<br>";
}
```

I'm trying to extract the first element inside of "result", however each of these elements are named differently so I'm not sure how to target it. For example, the first two currency pairings returned are "BCHEUR" and "BCHUSD".

So with the loop I have above, it just echos "Array" repeatedly... not what I'm going for.

How do I target that element so I can loop through each one? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are aiming to do? You first say you are trying to *extract the first element*... but then you say you want to loop through each one? Which is it?

Comment: meant im trying to loop through the first element..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, the json structure is:

[image]

You need to use:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {    

}
```

In this case:

```
foreach ($kraken_coins['result'] as $coin => $coindata) {    
    echo $coin . "<br>";
}
```